# Library creation in JAVA using modules in JAVA 9

Tags: java, maven, build, jar, shared-libraries

I want to create a library in JAVA with all its dependencies contained in it so that the versions of the dependencies do not conflict with the versions that may be available in the environment in which the library will be used. I have explored the concept of a module in JAVA. I was also able to create a module using Maven in Eclipse. Now I am not sure how to create a JAR out of it. Or is there any alternative to a modular jar for such a library. ( P.S. I am very new to JAVA)

Comment: *all its dependencies contained in it* This is not the way that Java libraries are customarily written.

Comment: Please don't put dependencies in a library JAR. This will cause all sorts of conflicts if people later use other versions of the dependency (unless you shade everything into different packages)

Comment: How can I shade everything into different packages? Or what is a better way to manage different versions of dependencies here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly it is not a module you would like to do, but rather a distribution with all jar files included.

To fix this you could do a [fat jar](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/maven/maven-build-fat-jar.html) with Maven.